# short sound stories/art/sound design pieces (no picture)

Tags: sound-design, art, stories

cau you please point me to some interesting sound design stuff, to get some inspiration.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IUDTlvagjJA

use headphones